# How does SE manage builds for QA

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

Joel Spolsky talks a lot about making sure the right build of the app is available to the QA team.  How does SE manage this with 100's of different sites and what I can only imagine is a huge log of new features you are working on.  How does the QA team access the right build?  Can you go "back in time" to old builds?

Comment: They use the same build for all sites, with only a very few minor variations, and some configuration switches.  They don't use custom builds for each site, although they do use custom CSS and graphics.

Answer (score 6):

I think we all know the answer to that...

[image]

Just kidding of course. [They do have a dev server and use mercurial for VC](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10369/172958).

Comment: HOw does the dev server help w/ QA builds?

Comment: Of course they test in production - why else do we have [[meta-tag:bug]]?